# Instagram API Follow Limit?

Tags: api, limit, instagram

I'm creating a simple app that allows users to log into my system and find other users similar to them (by thumbnail). Once they click on the thumbnail, they should automatically follow that user

However I keep getting 'you have reached your limit'. After doing a search I found that the follow limit on the hour is 350. However, I only followed about 10 times and I get this message. It won't let me follow anyone anymore through the api. Even if I change the client id and secret, I still get the 'limit' message

Just an fyi, the way I have it set up now:

1. user connects to my site,
2. grants my app permission to write to their account
3. redirected back to my site. All users will use the same client ID and secret, and will be granted their own unique token

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem too. I created my app, but it looks like instagram limits your rate limit per app id.  It's something like 3500 per hour.  Also, they track requests from IP addresses, so try using different proxies for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, have the same issue. I'm not seeing a whole lot of consistency with the rate limit being reached and there's no way I'm at the limit the docs mention. I've even hardcoded delays to ensure that nothing happens too fast and I'm still making no progress with this.